# How to copy multiple rows but change one field with mysql

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table such as:

```
val cols cole
1   1    3
2   1    5
4   1    9
2   6    8
3   1    9
1   4    9
2   9    9
```

I want a query that duplicates all rows where val=2 but change val to 5 for these new rows.

Resulting in:

```
val cols cole
1   1    3
2   1    5
4   1    9
2   6    8
3   1    9
1   4    9
2   9    9
5   1    5
5   6    8
5   9    9
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you want a `SELECT` query, or an `INSERT`?

Here's a `SELECT` that should work for you:

```
select val, cols, cole
from your_table
UNION ALL
select 5 as val, cols, cole
from your_table
where val = 2
```

Here's an `INSERT`:

```
insert into your_table (val, cols, cole)
select 5 as val, cols, cole
from your_table
where val = 2
```